# What is the return type of the imshowpair command in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have tried all possible means to figure out the return type of `imshowpair` command in MATLAB but I still was not able to find its return type.

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me its return type.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, using [`class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) is a very easy way to determine the type of a variable that is returned by a function.

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html?refresh=true#outputarg_h), the output of `imshowpair` is simply the graphics handle to the image object that is created.

```
h = imshowpair(rand(10), rand(10));

class(h)

     matlab.graphics.primitive.Image
```

You can use this graphics handle to change the appearance of the displayed image. You can call `get(h)` to get a list of all properties you can get/set and their current values. The [documentation for the image object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html) provides a complete list along with the description of each of these properties.

Answer (score 2):

There are three major ways to do so:

1. Thanks to the help. By browsing the help page for `imshowpair()`, which can be found [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html?refresh=true), you can click on the output *h* and the hyperlink will show you some infos about it which, in this case, is:

> handle to Handle Graphics image object.
>   Image object, returned as a
>   handle to the Handle Graphics image object created by imshowpair.

2. Thanks to the Workspace. In Matlab you can setup your window layout in order to show the Workspace that is a list of all the Matlab variables you have in memory. In the Workspace you can as well show the class (type). In this case you'll see something like (excuse my tiny Workspace window):
   [image]
3. Thanks to the `class()` function. I have `C` as output from `imshowpair()` and by typing `class(C)` I get:

   ```
   matlab.graphics.primitive.Image
   ```

   which is the same result as in the Workspace case.